# CMake ordering of include paths

Tags: cmake

I have an `IMPORTED` static library (say `foo`) that I want to link against. I'm building it within my source tree using `ExternalProject_Add`, and then create an `IMPORTED` library target for which I set the appropriate properties (`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` for the headers, and `IMPORTED_LOCATION` for the binary).

I also have a globally installed version of the same library, whose headers are installed under `/usr/local/include`. Unfortunately, another package (specifically `FindPackage(LibLZMA)`) used by my build also has headers installed in `/usr/local/include`.

The pseudo-script looks like this:

```
FindPackage(libLZMA)

add_library(foo STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libfoo.a)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${foo_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(bar ${bar_SOURCES}
target_link_libraries(bar foo)
```

Now the problem is that cmake generates the following order of includes (they are all added as system includes) for `bar`:

1. `/usr/local/include`
2. `foo_INCLUDE_PATH`

So when building, I'm actually picking up the headers for the global installation of `foo`, rather than for my local, vendored version. I do however link my local version, but the two don't match, leading to runtime errors.

So, I need some way to ensure that `foo_INCLUDE_PATH` is searched first (or, more generally, that `/usr/local/include` is searched last). How can this be done?

Comment: I guess you already tried to switch the order of `${foo_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `${LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIRS}` when you set `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, and it doesn't affect the command-line that is being generated.

Comment: Does the bar target have any (system) include directories set? Add the generated compiler command line (say, from 'make VERBOSE=1') to your question could be useful.
Also, does target_include_directories(foo INTERFACE ${foo_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
instead of set_property() change anything?

Comment: `bar`does have other includes, but no system includes. Explicitly setting `target_include_directories` on `foo` doesn't change the behavior. I'll try to create a minimal example.

Comment: Does `target_include_directories(foo BEFORE INTERFACE ${foo_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIRS})` give you what you want? Note, the [`BEFORE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html#target-include-directories) will *prepend* these include directories before other entries for that target property. Hope this helps!